# How can I save attachments with different criteria into two different folders in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I get 2 different files forwarded to me in Outlook daily. I currently use the code below to automatically download the attachments that meet the criteria to a folder on my drive.

I was wondering if there is a way to edit this so that I can save the different files to two different folders. i.e. email with A in subject => save attachment to folder A, email with B in subject => save attachment to folder B.

```
Public Sub SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oOutlookAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveAttachmentsFolder As String
    sSaveAttachmentsFolder = "C:\Users\mason\Desktop\Email Pricing\"
    For Each oOutlookAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oOutlookAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveAttachmentsFolder & 
        oOutlookAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

I know nothing about VBA, I just found this code online.

Comment: What are your criteria? Is it just the subject line? And which directories would you like to save them?

Comment: Yes, the criteria is that the subject line contains either string A or string B. If it contains string A, I would like to save it to folder A on my desktop. If it contains string B, I would like to save it to folder B on my desktop. as a secondary, I would only like to save the attachment if it is a .csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a binary criterion (A or B), we don't need to consider both strings: if it contains A, save to `folderA`. Else (which means it contains B) save to `folderB`.

```vb
Public Sub SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim FolderA As String, FolderB As String, StringA As String

    FolderA = "C:\Users\mason\Desktop\Email Fast Racks\"
    FolderB = "C:\Users\mason\Desktop\Email FTS Pricing\"
    StringA = "Fast Racks East Coast"
    For Each oAttach In MItem.Attachments

            If UCase(oAttach.FileName) Like "*.CSV" Then
                If InStr(MItem.Subject, StringA) > 0 Then
                    oAttach.SaveAsFile FolderA & oAttach.DisplayName
                Else
                    oAttach.SaveAsFile FolderB & oAttach.DisplayName
                End If
            End If

    Next oAttach

End Sub
```

Comment: I fixed your code and it runs. Problem was the with oAttach clause. .Subject needed to be preceded by MItem not oAttach.

Answer (score 0):

*You could also simply use **[Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)***

*Example*

```
Public Sub SaveOutlookAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oOutlookAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveAttachmentsFolder As String

    Debug.Print MItem.Subject

    Select Case MItem.Subject
            '// subject line A
        Case "AAAA"
            sSaveAttachmentsFolder = "C:\Users\mason\Desktop\Email Pricing\AAAA\"
            '// subject line B
        Case "BBBB"
            sSaveAttachmentsFolder = "C:\Users\mason\Desktop\Email Pricing\BBBB\"
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Subject not found"
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    For Each oOutlookAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oOutlookAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveAttachmentsFolder & oOutlookAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```